# Get first letter from string in php and insert a html command

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to get first character from string and insert a html command for it.

```
<?php
    $str = nl2br($personal_data['about']);
    if $str[0] {
?>
    <span class="dropcap">
<?php }  echo $str[0] ?>
```

I try something like that, but don't works.

Please, give me another idea for do that.

Thanks for help!

Comment: if ($str[0]) { and not for "her" but for "it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function **substr()** for get the letters you want.

```
substr ( $YourString, Int StartLetter, Int NumberLetter)
```

So for you that will be like this.

```
$str = substr ( $personal_data['about'] , 0 , 1 )
```

Hope this helps.